# Can "fsolve (scipy)" find many roots of a function?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I read in the scipy documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) that **fsolve** : *Find the root**S** of a function.*
But even, with a simple example, I obtained only **one** root

```
def my_eq(x):
    y = x*x-1
    return y

roots = fsolve(equation,0.1)
print(roots)
```

So, is it possible to obtain multiple roots with fsolve in one call ?

For other solvers, it is clear in the doc (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#id2). They *Find **a** root of a function*

(N.B. I know that multiple root finding is difficult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the docs are a bit vague in that respect. The plural root**s** refers to the fact that both `scipy.optimize.root` and `scipy.optimize.fsolve` try to find one N-dimensional point x (root) of a multivariate function F: R^N -> R^N with F(x) = 0.

However, if you want to find multiple roots of your scalar function, you can write it as a multivariate function and pass different initial guesses:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def my_eq(x):
    y1 = x[0]*x[0]-1
    y2 = x[1]*x[1]-1
    return np.array([y1, y2])

x0 = [0.1, -0.1]
roots = fsolve(my_eq,[0.1, -0.1])
print(roots)
```

This yields all roots [1, -1].

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.optimize.root` or `scipy.optimize.fsolve` only returns a single root closest to the `x0` unless the `func` is a system of equations. So I think it cannot return multiple roots at once given only one scalar equation in this case.

A work around:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def func(x):
    f = x ** 2 - 1
    return f


# find the roots between 5 and -5
v1 = fsolve(func, np.array(5))  # solution closest to x= 5 is 1
v2 = fsolve(func, np.array(-5))  # solution closest to x= -5 is -1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 200)
ax.plot(t, func(t), label='$y = x^2 -1$')
ax.plot(t, np.zeros(t.shape), label='$y = 0$')
ax.plot(v1, func(v1[0]), "o", label=f'root1 = {v1[0]}')
ax.plot(v2, func(v2[0]), "o", label=f'root2 = {v2[0]}')
ax.legend()

print(f'root1 = {v1[0]}, root2 = {v2[0]}')

plt.show()
```

[image]